# VBA code showing "Compile error: Sub or function not defined"

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, excel-formula

I have this following code which is showing this error: "Compile error: Sub or function not defined"

```
Dim wattarray() As Integer 
Dim x As Integer

x = Sheets("Names").Range("ai4")
ReDim wattarray(x) As Integer
Dim battarray As Variant
If condition Then
    battarray = Array("32", "34", "36")
End if

For z = 1 To x
    watt = (kw * 1000 * dmarg) / (ieff * battarray(z) * tfac * agefac * 6 * nstring)
    wattarry(z) = watt      "this line shows the error"           
    watt = wattarry(1)
Next z
```

battarray and wattarray have the same size as variable `x`

Can some one help me fix this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wattarray()`, not `wattarry()` !

Make sure you use `Option Explicit` in every module. This can be automated by changing VBE preferences: Tools/ Options/ Require Variable Declaration.